# Access values of Go struct in external function

Tags: function, struct, go

I have the following function declararion, which works and prints out correctly.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
)

func LatestTag(user, project string) {

    client := github.NewClient(nil)
    releases, _, err := client.Repositories.ListTags(user, project, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        release := releases[0]
        fmt.Printf("Version: %+v\n", *release.Name)
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I have modified the function to return a string (I don't think this is right) but hopefully it can help shed some light on what I am trying to do.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
)

func LatestTag(user, project string) string {

    client := github.NewClient(nil)
    releases, _, err := client.Repositories.ListTags(user, project, nil)
    var release string

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        release := releases[0]
    }
    return *release.Name
}
```

I would like to return the value of `*release.Name` rather than just print it out so that I can access the value from another function but I don't understand how returning works in this case (very new to Go).

I was thinking I could just return the struct as a string but get errors when I run it.

```
release.Name undefined (type string has no field or method Name)
```

Which makes me think that I'm not approaching this correctly.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I wonder if that error is really coming from elsewhere in your code, not that snippet -- `release` sure looks like it should be a [RepositoryTag](http://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-github/github#RepositoryTag) there, not a string. ([This](http://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-github/github) is the library I'm reasonably sure you're using.)

Comment: re: "I don't understand how returning works in this case (very new to Go)," early on in your Go trek it may be worth some working through [the Tour](http://tour.golang.org/) or [searching the spec for `return`-related stuff](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements) or even poking through some code that interests you in the stdlib or on GitHub.

Comment: @twotwotwo the snippet posted is working, I get errors when I try returning.  Would it be helpful to post another snippet that produces the error?  Part of my confusion is that I don't understand how to return RepositoryTag, so I started out with string since I only want the Name value but am stuck.

Comment: if release.Name work, *realease.Name never cause 'release.Name undefined'

Comment: Post updated to include the github package along with the code that isn't working.

Comment: Hmm, the line `release := releases[0]` is actually just declaring a variable *inside that `else` block*. You're accessing something else called `releases` (a variable declared elsewhere in the function or a package global) in the `return` statement. [The spec says](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) (in item 5 in the numbered list, in spec-like language) that variable declarations are only in scope until the end of the block, which differs from, say, how Python does it.

Comment: Returning a `*RepositoryTag` is like returning a `string`; the only gotcha is you always prefix identifiers from other packages with the package name in Go, so you need to say `*github.RepositoryTag` not just `*RepositoryTag`.

Comment: @twotwotwo  so it seems nothing about golang, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
var release string
...
if err != nil {
...
} else {
    release := releases[0]  // <-- here
}
```

At the line indicated you define a *new* variable called `release` equal to `releases[0]` which is scoped only to the `else` clause (use of `:=`). That then goes out of scope immediately. I'm surprised you don't get an unused variable warning. Looks like you also need to change the type of `release` to `github.RepositoryTag`. Try:

```
var release github.RepositoryTag
...
if err != nil {
...
} else {
    release = releases[0]  // note equals sign
}
```

However a more idiomatic way to do this would be something like (untested):

```
func LatestTag(user, project string) (string, error) {
    client := github.NewClient(nil)
    if releases, _, err := client.Repositories.ListTags(user, project, nil); err != nil {
        return "", err
    } else {
        release := releases[0]
        return *release.Name, nil
    }
}
```

Comment: An even more idiomatic approach is to move the call to ListTags to its own statement and the else block to the top-level of the function.  The if statement because `if err != nil { return "", err }`.  [Golint](https://github.com/golang/lint) will complain about the code as written.

Comment: This works.  I am still not sure how to do determine `github.RepositoryTag` variable.     I'm sure it is obvious to others but I don't have a lot of experience so it is a little confusing to me still.

Comment: What do you mean by *'determine'*? If you mean 'declare', you don't need to do so explicitly. The `:=` operator will give the variable the same type as the function returns.

Comment: @abligh Why is the release variable declared as `github.RepositoryTag` rather than a string?  If I don't know what type of variable to use, what is an easy way to find out?

Comment: @jmreicha because it contains more than just the name: https://gowalker.org/github.com/google/go-github/github#RepositoryTag